# Re-run statements upon variable change in Svelte

Tags: svelte

it's my first time using Svelte and I'm trying to build an app where a user selects an item from the dropdown menu and then the main content changes based off of what they selected.

However, upon changing a selection, I want a series of statements to execute each time based off of that change in order to re-calculate my main content. Currently, these statements don't execute.

**MyComponent.svelte**

```
<script>
    let controls
    
    let layout = getLayout(controls)
    console.log(layout)
</script>

<div>
    <MyDropdown bind:controls />
    
    
    <!-- main content area -->
    {#if layout.active}
        <p>Active</p>
    {/if}
    
    {#each layout.content as item}
        <div>{item.id} - {item.description}</div>
    {/each}
</div>
```

The `getLayout` call only executes once and I want it to execute each time a dropdown selection is selected. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not marking the `layout` assignment as [reactive](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-components#script-3-$-marks-a-statement-as-reactive):

```js
$: layout = getLayout(controls);
$: console.log(layout);
```